# How do I find Client ID in Google Adwords Scripts

Tags: google-ads-api

Question 1: -
I am using the script below which works fine, but cant seem to get the Client ID (eg Bobs Bakers) I have many clients and want to run this from within google adwords scripts. (Not the API).

Question 2:
Is there a way to run this across all clients, giving me all campaigns they have? Or do I have to run this script from within each client?

```
function main() {
var campaignsIterator = AdWordsApp.campaigns()
  .withCondition("Status = ENABLED");
  .forDateRange('TODAY')
  .get();

var csv = 'CampaignName, Impressions,Clicks,AveragePosition,AverageCpc,ConversionRate,Conversions,Ctr,Cost';
while (campaignsIterator.hasNext()) 

{
var campaign = campaignsIterator.next();
var stats = campaign.getStatsFor("TODAY");
var row = [
                            campaign,
                            stats.getImpressions(),
           stats.getClicks(),
           stats.getAveragePosition(),
           stats.getAverageCpc(),
           stats.getConversionRate(),
           stats.getConversions(),
           stats.getCtr(),
           stats.getCost()];

csv += '\n' + row.join(',');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. can't find the customer name, but here's a way to see the account id:

   AdWordsApp.currentAccount().getCustomerId()
2. running the same script across accounts isn't possible as of yet. You'll have to run the script from within each client.